# Jira query for In Progress sub-task within a task

Tags: jira, jql

I'm pretty new to Jira and been stuck for the last 2 days.
So far I have been able to pull info from task or sub-stask separately but I want to pull the data wihtin one query in order to visualize the information I need.

Task query:
`project in ("xyz","wxyz") and status in ( "In Progress") and issuetype in (task)`

Sub-task query:
`project in ("xyz","wxyz") and status in ( "In Progress") and issueType in subTaskIssueTypes()`

The task has x number of subtask and I want to show the ones that are in progress and which task number is

With the Task query I can see the info from the below image, but what I'm trying to achieve is to add the subtask(I plut in red what im trying to get)

[image]

So far I have been reading documentation but no lucky with the info.
I don't have access to plugins or third party solutions.

Answer (score 0):

you can find your wanted issues by setting the query

```
project in ("xyz","wxyz") and status in ( "In Progress") and parent = "ISSUE-KEY"
```